# How to pass mouse on to client apps in Byobu?

Tags: mouse, byobu

I have been able to set up Byobu to use the mouse (Alt-F12), but nothing I do allows Byobu to pass mouse events to client programs.  I can only get mouse support for controlling Byobu itself.

Is there a combination of settings which allows the mouse to control Byobu and to be utilized within client progams in Byobu windows?